# Qt5 Signal and slots does not seem to work

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I am trying to change a label's text to a slider's value when the slider moves. My slider is named `sld_bet` and my label is `lbl_bet`. `sld_bet_changed()` is a function that only has a breakpoint in it, and will eventually contain `lbl_bet`'s modifying code.

The breakpoint is never reached, and I do not understand why.

```
app::app(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    connect(ui.sld_bet, SIGNAL(ui.sld_bet->sliderMoved()),
        this, SLOT(sld_bet_changed()));
}
```

Comment: You're not using the correct syntax. Should be `SIGNAL(sliderMoved())`. Is `sld_bet_changed` defined as a slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Qt 5, use the new connect syntax. That way the compiler will throw an error if something is not correct.

```
connect(ui.sld_bet, &QSlider::sliderMoved, this, &app::sld_bet_changed);
```

Comment: Is there a spot where there is a tutorial for qt5? I pulled my code mostly from the qt docs.

Comment: [woboq](http://woboq.com/) has very nice tutorials and blogs, also if you are interested in the internals of how many Qt things work, on the Qt 5 signals and slots you should look at: [Signals and Slots in Qt5](http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html)

Answer (score 4):

change to

```
connect(ui.sld_bet, SIGNAL(sliderMoved()), this, SLOT(sld_bet_changed()));
```

Comment: Thank you, however I should mention that I am using qt5, and this doesn't work with qt5.

Comment: hmm im using it with qt5 with no problems. But if you're using qt5 it is advised too use the new signal slot syntax. im just too lazy to convert all mine over in older projects. https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @DevGuy FYI: Not sure if you are aware of this but you can use the latest Qt Creator quick fixes to automatically convert the old syntax to the new one (one-by-one unfortunately). Just put the cursor on the connect statement, press ALT + Enter (default except if changed) and select "convert connect() to Qt 5 Syle".

Comment: @TheBadger i was not aware thanks, one by one is better than nothing :)